# Wifi 5GHz does not work, my band tu is all disabled. I doesn't see my 5ghz router

Tags: drivers, wireless, network-manager, broadcom

Here is my terminal `iw phy`
[image: here is my terminal]

```
iw reg get:
```

> [iw reg get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ004.png)

So somebody can help me with this? I cannot find any usable help to
work my wireless 5ghz connection.

My PCie card: `06:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4360
802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)`

```
Current `iwconfig` 

 wlp6s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"essid"  
           Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: AC:22:05:C7:80:E5   
           Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
           Power Management:on
```

Its a Tp Link Archer Ac1900 T9E  And i USE `bcmwl-kernel driver`

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `iw reg get` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I edited, thx for your help!!!

Comment: What channel is your 5 gHz router on? Find out: `sudo iwlist scan` Is it part of your main router? With the same or different name, such as *my_router_5* ?

Comment: I have a router and it have 2 separated wifi networks one 2.4ghz and the another is 5ghz

Comment: Are they named the same (bad) or named differently (good)? Is the 5 gHz segment visible with `sudo iwlist scan` or not? What channel is it on? Not auto-select, we hope.

Comment: I see it  on iwlist scan : Cell 07 - Address: AC:22:05:C7:80:BD
                    Channel:36
                    Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
                    Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"5ghz"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from scanning, the router is on channel 36. The image you posted, the result of `iw list`, shows channel 36 as an available channel.

Your `iw reg get` shows that your country code is unset. As the permissible channels often varies from one country to another, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Now do you see your router?

```
nmcli dev wifi list
```

Can you connect?

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working!