# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - Detecting 5GHz wifi takes long time

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi

I have two hidden wifi networks in range of my laptop (2.4 GHz and 5 GHz); immediately after a boot, I see only the 2.4 GHz network; the 5 GHz becomes visible only after a minute or two. After this delay, I can connect to it and use it, but the fact that I have to wait two minutes is somehow annoing.

```
$ lspci -k -nn | grep -A 3 -i net

5c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 73)     
        DeviceName: WLAN 
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:4070]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

$ modinfo iwlwifi
filename:      /lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license: 
GPL author:    Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com> 
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
```

My computer has a dual boot with Windows 10, and I don't have this issue; both networks are detected immediately.

I'm currently running Ubuntu 20.04 but I had this issue also with 19.10.

Is there any magic option I could try to speed-up the 5GHz network detection?

Thanks & best regards

Comment: Been noticing the same issue over the last couple months I think. Very annoying. Also on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, adding the correct country (FR in my case) in /etc/default/crda as explained here [Wifi 5GHz does not work, my band tu is all disabled. I doesn't see my 5ghz router](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022681/wifi-5ghz-does-not-work-my-band-tu-is-all-disabled-i-doesnt-see-my-5ghz-route) did the job; Now the computer connects instantly to the 5 GHz network.

(I'm now using 20.10 and no longer 20.04 but the problem was still there, and disappeared only after changing the country settings).

EDIT: actually, after a kernel upgrade, I had again to run the command 'sudo iw reg set FR' ...